# How to send content of textfields in view B to view A?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I created a `tableview A` in  `UIView A`, with a `tabledatasource` from a plist file defined in the A.m file. The entries in the `tableview` are dictionaries with `keyA`, `keyB`, `keyC`, and etc.

Now I'm going to create a `UIButton` in `UIView` A and a new modalview B. When the button  is pressed , modalview B will pop up. In modalview B, there will be a few `UITextfields` to be filled in by the users. The information that user fill in the textfields will write to the plist file(as mentioned above), and then reload the content of the tableview A.

My question is, users fill in informations in modalview B. But the tableview A is in the `UIView` A. It seems that I can not change the content of tableview A when I am currently using the App on the modalview B?

If there's a way that I can pass the informations entered in view B to view A?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Use custom Protocals -  This is called delegate pattern

//ClassA.h

```
@interface : ClassA{
}
@end
```

ClassB.h

```
@protocol ClassBDelegate;

@interface :  ClassB{

    id <ClassBDelegate> delegate
}

@property(nonatomic,assign)   id <ClassBDelegate> delegate;
@end
@protocol ClassBDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)classB:(ClassB*)bclass param1:(NSString*)p1 param2:(NSString*)p2 param3:(NSString*)p3;

@end
```

Set delegate to ClassA - receiver

In button action (in Class b)
just say

```
[self.delegate classB:self param1:@"Param1" param2:@"P2" param3:@"p3"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You typically achieve this behavior using the delegate pattern. Check out the example iPhoneCoreDataRecipes in the Apple documentation. In particular look at the classes

- RecipeListTableViewController, where your table view A is going to be
- RecipeAddViewController, the modal view B where you get the information

Answer (score 0):

I think i misunderstood your question. ok so like sanjeev said you can use delegates. Or you can use NSNotification. Add a notification Observer in View A and in view B where you are modifying plist Post a notification.
[See This Example](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/Sounden/Simple%20NSNotificationCenter%20example)

Comment: You can use any thing to achieve your functionality, NSnotification is a bit heavy than the protocals, Personally i feel Protocal is enough in your case